# Transparency on TIFF on specific area

Tags: python, gdal, transparency-opacity

I am using `gdal_translate` and `gdaldem` to produce and color a GeoTIFF starting from a NetCDF file representing a temperature field.
I am able to produce the TIFF (temperature.tiff) of my domain with a constant transparency but not able to change transparency with the position.

I would like to set different transparency values depending on the position (e.g no transparency on land, and transparent on sea).

I have a NetCDF file of my domain masked (domain.nc), with value =1 on land and =0 on the sea. From this I can produce its corresponding TIFF (domain.tiff) where I set the "transparency mask" with fully transparency on sea and no transparency on land.

Can I use the domain file to set the correct transparency also on the temperature TIFF?
If not, is there another way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure about the domain portion of your question, you can remove the undesired pixels by using the reclassify tool and changing the value of the pixels to NODATA.

In your example, you would change all sea pixels to NODATA and leave the land pixels unchanged.

[image][image]

In the picture I removed all pixels of a certain value which allows you to see the layer behind the image.
Note that this only works for display, as those pixels still exist, they are simply not displaying any information, so any raster math would have to contend with the NODATA pixels.